# Is there a decision algorithm with time complexity of Ө(n²)?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, notation, big-o

Is there a decision problem with a time complexity of Ө(n²)?

In other words, I'm looking for a decision problem for which the best known solution has been *proven* to have a lower bound of N².

I thought about searching for the biggest number in matrix but the problem is that matrix is an input of O(n²) so the solution is linear.

It doesn't need to be known problem, a hypothetical one would suffice as well.

Comment: Obviously you didn't bother to do a simple Internet search. I just typed "O n^2 decision problems" into the search bar and presto, the following PDF came up: [*"Computing a Frobenius Coin Problem decision problem in O(n^2 )"*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0961.pdf) Spend some time searching before posting questions that simply cause noise. It took *less time* than creating an account and posting a question here... I'm sure if you spend more than 30 seconds doing a smart(er) search you'll find something better.

Comment: Belive me - I tried. And this solution is not big Ө of n^2. It's big O of n^2/

Comment: @ray I need something you can't (and it's proven) solve faster.. like finding the largest num in array is big Ө of n...I already had  bubble sort which is big O of n^2. but I need big Ө of n^2.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference between big-O and big-Ө, that's why I said a smarter search might be more helpful than my 10-second test. Did you check Google Scholar at least? What about computer science text books on algorithms?

Comment: @ray Yeah...I'm searching for a couple of days...It's not so simple to search that.. It's not so common question and the symbols are un-searchable sometimes..

Comment: I've made some edits to your post to improve wording and fix some typos. I had to change the word 'problem' for 'algorithm' in the title b/c the site complains about it. Either way, your question may need more clarification. You might want to include some actual examples of problems you've already looked at to give readers a sense of what you're looking for.

Comment: @ray And thank for the edit... I have to say it's looks great! :)

Comment: About searching "the biggest number in a square matrix": even if the optimal solution is linear in the *number of cells*, it will always be quadratic in terms of the *length of the diagonal*, so it really is Ө(n²) if you choose `n` to mean that.

Comment: This kind of question is **much better** asked on [ComputerScience.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). Stackoverflow is about *programming*, not computer science. Also: [your question has been already asked and answered there](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/problems-that-provably-require-quadratic-time)

Comment: How about "Find if for two elements x & y in an array P(x,y) is true" where P is some constant-time predicate?

Comment: @Ap31 That is certainly true. However one could argue that the actual problem is finding whether a predicate P holds on a set of pairs(x, y) where x and y belong to a certain set, and in that case the size would be the size of the set, i.e. you'd again obtain O(n) instead of O(n^2).  This happens all the time: the size of a problem is a choice and as such complexity can be manipulated in some reasonable ways.

Comment: @Bakuriu Agreed, predicate certainly should not be part of the input, but if it is known beforehand, it can often be used to optimize the whole algorithm, e.g. if P(x,y) is (x==y) then the whole task can be done in O(n log n). So the question is - is there a predicate to guarantee Ө(n²)?

Comment: Given n numbers, is there exist a pair (x,y) whose product xy  is divisible by all n numbers?

Comment: @JonHameratesh you have two answers, aren't you going to say anything?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a theoretical computer science question, rather than a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Does a close pair exist?**

In any "difficult" metric space, given `n` points, does a pair exist in distance less than `r`, where `r` is an *input* parameter?

---

Intuitively proof:

Given that `r` is an input parameter, you have to search every point.

For a point, you have compute the distance to every other point, that's Θ(n).

For `n` points, you have n*Θ(n) = Ө(n²).

---

Time complexity: Ө(n²)

Comment: What are difficult metric spaces? Non-Euclidean?

Comment: @n.m. there a tons of them, non-Euclidean as well. My point is that it shouldn't be something trivial.

Comment: Is there any accessible proof?

Comment: I made that up from my mind @n.m., if someone searches for it, it might be available. ;)

Comment: The problem here is that in R^n the complexity is known to be O(n log n). Why should anyone believe without a proof that it's worse for other spaces?

Comment: @n.m. what? I cannot understand, I am sorry.. :/

Comment: I think what @n.m. saying is that there is a domain of input, which is known to have a O(n lg n) soln for this problem, is there any other "difficult" space?

Comment: @n.m. but I have another question to ask your opinion. To answer OP, do you think the problem to solve has to be theta(n^2) for ALL possible input space?  or only there exists one "hard" space which makes the problem only solvable in theta(n^2)?

Comment: It's enough to show that the problem is n^2-hard in one space of course. But it's not enough to state that without a proof.

Comment: It's trivial, isn't it? I mean I made that out of my head n.m., I didn't search for it. If someone wants a proof, (s)he is welcome to search and report back. :)

Comment: @gsamaras OP has asked for a problem with a **proven** complexity bound. You have proposed a problem. If you cannot produce a proof foor it,  (1) don't say "it's trivial" and (2) don't call it an answer.

Comment: @n.m. I updated, hope it's better now and you will retrieve your downvote.. :/

Comment: I didn't downvote, I rarely do,  but you don't have anything that resembles a vslid proof. You need to prove that no algorithm can be faster than that. You haven't even started to analyze the situation, you just show an algorithm and say here, this is the fastest one possible (which is false).

Comment: That's too broad @n.m., I will not delete my answer, and if something better comes, let it be! :)